# How to save / export Whatsapp stickers as webp images?

Tags: android, whatsapp, whatsapp-stickers

I want to use whatsapp stickers outside of the app.

- `/storage/emulated/0/Whatsapp/Media/Whatsapp Stickers` only contains the stickers which I've sent / recieved.
- It looks like Whatsapp keeps all the stickers in a encrypted file - `stickers.db.crypt1`.

So, is there a way to export all the stickers or to decrypt the `.crypt1` file ?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little bit lame solution, but what I did was:

1. Created a new group chat just with me and my friend
2. Kicked my friend out off the group
3. Sent all the stickers into the group (so just to myself)
4. Connected my phone to my laptop with a cable and copied the files from `/storage/emulated/0/Whatsapp/Media/Whatsapp Stickers`

Sending the stickers is really fast, but if I had more than a few hundreds of them, I would probably keep searching for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

you will find all stickers in
/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/Whatsapp/Media/Whatsapp Stickers